# How can i push data with custom id in real time database with React JS?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to send data in the form of id: value under requestList to realtime database. The data I want to send comes in the form of a list.[image]

these are the codes i wrote

```
  const driverRequestList = () => {
    fireDb
      .child(`All Ride Requests/${id}`)
      .child("requestListy")
      .update(driverIdList)
      .catch(alert);
  };

   Object.keys(idleDriver).map((id) => {
      if (
        !!carType &&
        carType === idleDriver[id].car_details.car_type &&
        !!province &&
        idleDriver[id].driverCurrentPosition.province === province.il &&
        !!district &&
        idleDriver[id].driverCurrentPosition.district === district
      ) {
        driverIdList.push(idleDriver[id].id);
      }
    });
```

I want it to come this way.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Object.entries(idleDriver).forEach(([key,value], index)=>{
 idleDriver[key]=value

})
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do

Comment: assign value of this object as a key, this should return what you want: From {key:"value"} it should return : {value:"value"}

Comment: That indeed look like the right approach Witold, although OP might want to use the `idleDriver[key] = key`. @okangulsevil: did you try the approach Witold suggested? If so, what result did you get?